# Подсчет количества заданного значения в столбцах Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

Дан массив данных потенциальных клиентов.
17 столбцов (образование, работа, доход), в которых множество значений "unknown".
Помогите пожалуйста создать код для подсчета и вывода количества значений "unknown" в каждом столбце, чтобы далее можно было оценить их значимость и поработать с очисткой.

Смог сделать только подсчет точечно по заданному столбцу (напр "education"), но если в столбце нет 'unknown' (напр "age") выдает ошибку.

```
X.education.value_counts()['unknown']

>>1857

X.education.value_counts()['age']

>>KeyError: 'age'
```

Пробовал создать цикл, но что-то не так

```
for i in range(0,len(X.columns)-1):
  val_unknown=X[X.columns[i]].value_counts()['unknown']
  print(X.columns[i], val_unknown)

>> KeyError: 'unknown'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё довольно просто:

```
import pandas as pd
from random import choice

s = ['unknown'] + list('всякая другая ерунда')

df = pd.DataFrame([[choice(s) for _ in range(10)] for _ in range(100)])
df.columns = [f'col{c}' for c in df.columns]

# собственно подсчёт здесь, выше подготовка случайных данных для примера
print((df == 'unknown').sum())
```

Вывод:

```
col0     6
col1     3
col2     3
col3     3
col4     4
col5     5
col6     8
col7     3
col8    11
col9     6
dtype: int64
```

Comment: (X == 'unknown').sum() - гениально и просто!

Спасибо!!

Comment: @alex_b В `Pandas` очень много всего есть для векторных и матричных операций, нужно просто немного привыкнуть )